# VS 2010 Class Diagram Error "The type cannot be edited..."

Tags: visual-studio-2010, class-diagram

A few of the classes on a VS 2010 class diagram are displayed with a red title.  The Class Details window shows all of the methods, properties, fields and correctly shows no events.  However, there's an entry under each of methods, properties, fields and events that states where the name should be:

> "The type cannot be edited because the
>   source code file contains an error."

However, the source file builds with no errors or warnings.

Anyone seen this? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: @volody: First thing I tried :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After rebooting, the error was gone.  I suspect just closing and re-opening VS 2010 may have done the same thing.